# Understanding a technique to make class-based decorators support instance methods

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-descriptors

I recently came across a technique in the Python decorator library's [`memoized`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) decorator which allows it to support instance methods:

```
import collections
import functools


class memoized(object):
    '''Decorator. Caches a function's return value each time it is called.
    If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned
    (not reevaluated).
    '''
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if not isinstance(args, collections.Hashable):
        # uncacheable. a list, for instance.
        # better to not cache than blow up.
            return self.func(*args)
        if args in self.cache:
            return self.cache[args]
        else:
            value = self.func(*args)
            self.cache[args] = value
            return value

    def __repr__(self):
        '''Return the function's docstring.'''
        return self.func.__doc__

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        '''Support instance methods.'''
        return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)
```

The `__get__` method is, as explained in the doc string, where the 'magic happens' to make the decorator support instance methods. Here are some tests showing that it works:

```
import pytest

def test_memoized_function():
    @memoized
    def fibonacci(n):
        "Return the nth fibonacci number."
        if n in (0, 1):
            return n
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

    assert fibonacci(12) == 144

def test_memoized_instance_method():
    class Dummy(object):
        @memoized
        def fibonacci(self, n):
            "Return the nth fibonacci number."
            if n in (0, 1):
                return n
            return self.fibonacci(n-1) + self.fibonacci(n-2)            

    assert Dummy().fibonacci(12) == 144

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([__file__])
```

What I'm trying to understand is: how does this technique work exactly? It seems to be quite generally applicable to class-based decorators, and I applied it in my answer to [Is it possible to numpy.vectorize an instance method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48981501/is-it-possible-to-numpy-vectorize-an-instance-method).

So far I've investigated this by commenting out the `__get__` method and dropping into the debugger after the `else` clause. It seems that the `self.func` is such that it raises a `TypeError` whenever you try to call it with a number as input:

```
> /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Scratch/memoize_fibonacci.py(24)__call__()
     23                         import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
---> 24                         value = self.func(*args)
     25                         self.cache[args] = value

ipdb> self.func
<function Dummy.fibonacci at 0x10426f7b8>
ipdb> self.func(0)
*** TypeError: fibonacci() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'
```

As I understand from [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**get**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__), defining your own `__get__` method somehow overrides what happens when you (in this case) call `self.func`, but I'm struggling to relate the abstract documentation to this example. Can anyone explain this step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, When you use a descriptor to decorate an instance method(actually, an attribute), it defines the behavior of how to `set`, `get` and `delete` this attribute. There is a [ref](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html#id6).

So in your example, `memoized`'s `__get__` defines how to get attribute `fibonacci`. In `__get__`, it pass `obj` to `self.__call__` which `obj` is the instance. And the key to support instance method is to fill in argument `self`.

So the process is:

Assume there is an instance `dummy` of `Dummy`. When you access to `dummy`'s attribute `fibonacci`, as it has been decorated by `memoized`. The value of attribute `fibonacci` is returned by `memoized.__get__`. `__get__` accept two arguments, one is the calling instance(here is `dummy`) and another is its type. `memoized.__get__` fill instance into `self.__call__` in order to fill in `self` argument inside original method `fibonacci`.

To understand descriptor well, there is an [example](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-example):

```
class RevealAccess(object):
    """A data descriptor that sets and returns values
       normally and prints a message logging their access.
    """

    def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
        self.val = initval
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print('Retrieving', self.name)
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print('Updating', self.name)
        self.val = val

>>> class MyClass(object):
...     x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')
...     y = 5
...
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.x
Retrieving var "x"
10
>>> m.x = 20
Updating var "x"
>>> m.x
Retrieving var "x"
20
>>> m.y
5
```